# Linkingoption for mariadb connector c

Tags: c++, linker, mariadb, linker-flags

Sooo, I am writing a C++ application to receive Data from a Socket and save it into a MariaDB database.

I included the MariaDB connector c library from the libmariadb3 package and it worked without a problem.

When compiling the program I had to add the linking option -l mysqlclient.

Compile command would be:

```
g++ main.cpp -o output -l mysqlclient
```

So my question is why do I have to add this linking option and how can I work around it so that I don't have to add this option?

(This is an example compile command. In reality I am compiling with cmake and I have compiled the mariadb connector c library myself. The linker option in cmake would be target_link_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC -lmysqlclient))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround, you need to link with the libraries you want to use.

In CMake, [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) simplifies this and adds the needed include paths and libs when compiling/linking.